# PHP error stacktrace - direct to a log file

Tags: php

I have some PHP scripts that are accessed by external non human sources.  Normally when a human accesses a page they will get the html error responses when an error occurs.  Is it possible to log these errors into a file that a person can look at later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own [error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to do it for you...  [This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#95206) may also be applicable...

Answer (score 0):

If the errors get logged you could use `ini_set("error_log", "file")`